# javascript html saving forms with webstorage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-storage

I want to use webstorage :sessionStorage for saving form records. When the user submits the form i have to print all the form values that were submited. 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        //some checks here....   

        if(!sessionStorage.getItem("mainForm")) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("mainForm", 0);
        }
        else {
            mainForm = sessionStorage.getItem("mainForm");
        }
        mainForm++;
        sessionStorage.setItem("mainForm",document.getElementById("id"));
        var text = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
            text += "Course id is" + i + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = text;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="mainForm" onsubmit="validateForm()">
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="7" required>

<input type="submit" value="Register">  
<p id="out" style="color:red"></p>
<p id="print"> </p>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

The above code does not work. Can you explain me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

`mainForm` is only defined in one branch of the if statement.  You can get rid of the `else` section around this line:

```
mainForm = sessionStorage.getItem("mainForm");
```

Maybe something like in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73o3opyg/).  However, I'm unsure what your code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Sorry for answering this late i had some internet connection issues. I found a solution to my problem just by using a counter var and increment it each time i submit the form.